# Solving inheritance contradictions among abc.Sequence, abc.Hashable and list in Python

Tags: python, abc

I'm using version 3.6.3

I'm studying Python `collections.abc`'s inheritance relationships among classes. And I found some contradictory inheritances among `list`, `Sequence` and `Hashable`

As you already know,
1. **`Sequence` inherits `Hashable` class** and
2. **`list` inherits `Sequence`**

```py
from collections import Sequence, Hashable


issubclass(Sequence, Hashable)  # 1.
issubclass(list, Sequence)      # 2.

True
True
```

From this, as you can possibly think **`list` also inherits `Hashable`** conceptually.

But **`list` is mutable and it doesn't inherit `Hashable`**(means 'you cannot '*hash(some_list)*')

```py
issubclass(list, Hashable)


False
```

I think this inheritance is contradictory. I totally understand `list` is mutable cause I've used `list` hundreds of times but inheritance relationship graph doesn't support this concept. What am I wrong or missing?

I wait for your adivce. Thank you.

Comment: Have you seen this blog: https://www.naftaliharris.com/blog/python-subclass-intransitivity/? It looks pretty good, here's a quote, "...Iterable is a "subclass" of Hashable--seriously, because Iterable has the `__hash__` method it inherits from object".

Comment: `Sequence` has a `__hash__` method, but according to https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes, `Sequence` does not inherit from `Hashable`.  (Not an answer, just an observation.)

Comment: @SuperShoot Thank you for your reference. I am a big fan of this kind of approach: Getting all classes in Python and testing all triplet dependency checks. I think I should dive into `metaclass` later.  :)

Comment: I've added that one to my reading list too. Thanks for the good Q and all the best with your Python learning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it is actually an interesting design feature, but Python subclasses don't actually need to be transitive. Transitive as defined by Google:

> "if a trait is applicable between successive members of a sequence, it must also apply between any two members taken in order. For instance, if A is larger than B, and B is larger than C, then A is larger than C."

For languages where inheritance is transitive, such as Java, if `B` inherits `A` and `C` inherits `B`, then `C` has to inherit `A`. The set of transitive super classes for `C` would be `A`, `B`, and `Object`, and the direct super class is `B`.

In Python we take a departure from this concept. As you pointed out, `Sequence` is `Hashable` and a `list` is a `Sequence`, but a `list` is not `Hashable`. In fact, list doesn't directly inherit anything *(apart from `object` which every python class inherits)*.

```
# from the PyCharm generated stubs
class list(object):
    ...
```

In Python you can use `__subclasscheck__` or `__subclasshook__` from the metaclass utilities to cause the builtin method `issubclass` to do interesting things. A meta class is an advanced language feature used to modify basic rules about how a class operates *(modifying how `issubclass` works being a great example)*. Within the abstract base class metaclass `ABCMeta`, the `__subclasscheck__` method will invoke the `__subclasshook__` method on a class if it is defined. You can read a [great answer about the uses here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40764347/python-subclasscheck-subclasshook).

Certain `ABCMeta` classes like `Hashable` implement `__subclasshook__` to not check an inheritance tree, but to check for the presence of a method. This is helpful such that common contracts don't have to be included in every class definition you make.

For this case, in order to be `Hashable` you need to define `__hash__`. However, Python states not to hash on a List because it is mutable and therefore it is specifically omitted from this class.

```
class Hashable(metaclass=ABCMeta):

    __slots__ = ()

    @abstractmethod
    def __hash__(self):
        return 0

    @classmethod
    def __subclasshook__(cls, C):
        if cls is Hashable:
            return _check_methods(C, "__hash__")
        return NotImplemented

class list(object):
    ...
    __hash__ = None
```

Comment: `class list(object):` doesn't appear anywhere in the actual definition of the `list` class. `class list(object)` appears in the `help(list)` output, and it might appear in PyCharm fake source code or something like that, but the [actual class definition](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.3/Objects/listobject.c) is in C.

Comment: @user2357112 ah thanks, good point, I'll add that in. It is still true that list only inherits object though; by virtue of being a python object.

Comment: Thank you my friend. It's very interesting Python classes doesn't simply comply with conceptual inheritance tree. But can you give me the meaning of `transitive`? I'm not an english speaker so it's kind of confusing to me.

Comment: @flakes Thank you, your edited answer is more clearer. But it got more issues for me too. Why does your code implement `subclasshook`, not `subclasscheck` and what is `_check_methods`? I got a point and appreciate it.

Comment: @flakes `subclasshook` and `subclasscheck` are very confusing and difficult to me, but I'll look for information. Thank you anyway :P

Comment: @Stonehead tried to explain it a bit better. The metaclass documentation is also a great resource https://realpython.com/python-metaclasses/

Comment: @flakes Please know that I really appreciate your effort to make a non faulty and clearer answer. My Python has improved. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @flakes Last question: what is the `checkmark`? Do you mean `flag?`